# Insert code into conditional

Tags: php

I want to insert this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

into a conditional function, like so:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()){
echo ...;
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Remember to accept my answer if it helped you, so other people can utilize this thread when they have the same problem as you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()): ?>
   <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Seriously? PHP tags within PHP?

Comment: Oh hahaha, sorry, just checked my code before... sorry!